# Ударение в слове «приближенный»

Tags: значение-слов, орфоэпия

...сегодня будем тренироваться в условиях, максимально приближенных к боевым.

Правильно ли в данном случае ударение на букву "и"?

Эта ссылка сбивает с толку, хотя словарь и толковый. Именно после неё захотелось спросить.
[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=приближенный&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

Comment: А почему Вы вообще на БТС Кузнецова в таком вопросе ориентируетесь? По вашей же ссылке есть Зарва (Русское словесное ударение), источник безусловно более авторитетный с точки зрения орфоэпии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не совсем понимаю ваши затруднения.
ПриблИженный и приближённый - это два разных слова, более того - две разных части речи.

Приближённый - прилигательное, используется 1) чаще всего как субстантиват (*приближённые*) - тут только Ё; или 2) в составе сочетаний, означающих некий круг лиц или объектов: *"лицо, приближённое к императору/двору"* - причем тут уже обсуждаем и вариант приблИженные. Приближённые результаты/функции - сюда же, здесь прилагательное, не причастие.

ПриблИженный - причастие, во всех остальных случаях: *условия, приближенные к Крайнему Северу*.

Словари (по вашей ссылке - в т. ч.) это подтверждают.

Вот Кузнецов, как всегда, оригинален, забыл про прИближенный. Но подобное у него встречается, он не орфоэпист ни разу.

(+)

> просто увидела, что там только один вариант и засомневалась.

Видимо потому, что не туда смотрели. Существование причастия Кузнецов не отрицает.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Кузнецов именно что забыл дать помету о существовании частично омографичного причастия. Это было бы важно знать с точки зрения орфоэпии, но не "толковой" семантики. А причастия, не имеющие самостоятельных значений Кузнецов просто не включает в словник, их у него надо искать по глаголу, да и там они не всегда представлены.

Comment: Спасибо, просто увидела, что там только один вариант и засомневалась.

Comment: Я подробно ответил на эту реплику в тексте самого ответа.